# Cant show articlesgroup when more then 3 records

Tags: sql

Hi i have a table called Artikelgroep in this table there are values called Artikelgroep like 'CD''DVD' i need to show those artikelgroeps when they have 3 or more records.

So i am trying this but is isnt working

```
SELECT Artikelgroep FROM tblArtikel where Artikelgroep > 3
```

Im getting this error message

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DVD' to data type int.
```

Comment: Clearly `Artikelgroep` is a string and you should not compare it to an integer.

Comment: You can put `3` in single quotes to do a string comparison, but that will be of little use I suspect.

Comment: @Bridge if i do that it also shows the lower then 3 ones.

Comment: You've edited your question to ask for something different to what the script does, that's why!

Comment: `Artikelgroep`  contains the value `DVD` and that can't be compared as a number.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you may need this. You need to group them together and do a count and select when count it more than 3

```
SELECT Artikelgroep, count(*) 
FROM tblArtikel 
GROUP BY Artikelgroep 
HAVING count(*) > 3;
```

Comment: @KipVerslaafde If this solves your problem, you can accept this answer and close this thread. (It has some timing restrictions :) )

Answer (score 1):

Posting the table structure would help, otherwise we have to guess it.

If my guess is correct the solution should be:

```
SELECT Artikelgroep,count(*) FROM tblArtikel group by Artikelgroep having count(*)>3
```